# How to open a downloaded file with a running instance

Tags: 13.04, firefox, multiple-instances

I want to open a file that I download (using firefox) with a running instance, instead of it opening it a new instance.

For example:
If I have gedit open and I download a textfile how can I make sure the textfile will be opened (automatically) by this running gedit instance?

I have found this:
[How to avoid opening a second instance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108765/how-to-avoid-opening-a-second-instance)
but it is still unclear for me how and mainly where to apply this.

Note: I am not specifically interested in opening files with gedit, but more in the general problem.

Answer (score 0):

In gedit, for example, you can do this by following the instructions from the following image:

[image: gedit]

In the same way you can open files from any associated program. In this mod you will not open for sure another instance of the program.